# How to create view with select two relation table one to one, and fill all null value with parent value - postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 2 tables, structured like this:

```
table A                   table B
- id                      - id
- name                    - name
- parent
- fk_b
```

so in table A there are parent and fk_b. for fk_b it can be null.
so if in table A (child) the fk_b is null will refer to table A (parent), for example on of the row in the table A (parent) has fk_b.

Note:
This parent contains the id of table A

my question is, how can we select table A join table B. But every table A with null fk_b will retrieve fk_b from its parent?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can self-join the table to retrieve the parent row, and implement conditional logic in the `on` clause of the join on `tableb`, like so:

```
select a.*, b.name
from tablea a
left join tablea p on p.id = a.parent
left join tableb b on b.id = coalesce(a.fk_b, p.fk_b)
```

Comment: its almost there, but there is still any empty value fo b.name. we need something like recursive to find fk_b until the root parent. so all row in table A will have a b.name from table B. here is example row 
https://gist.github.com/darmawan01/c1793e4c2d0123d2219a11a8ef24ec84